# How to add sort buttons to an excel spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spread sheet with 6 columns (A-F)

```
A- WO#
B- Priority
C- Equipment #
D- Description
E- Brief Description of Problem
F- Shutdown WO Y/N
```

I want to be able to install a button that will sort the data by priority and one to sort the data by WO#. What would be the macro that I would need to do this? There will be no more columns added but the amount of rows of data will always be changing. Ive tried to make my own but cant get it to work when I start to add more rows of data.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: Do you really need a macro for this? If you put a filter on the columns, in the filter options there is a Sort, which seems to be all you'd need.

Comment: Get started with the macro recorder and record your actions. Take a look at what you've created when done.

Answer (score 2):

Highlight the columns, go to `Data` tab, click `Filter`, then in the column drop-down menu, you can choose `sort`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to create your own sort button or simply trying to sort data in a specific order?

**Here's instructions for the latter:**
1.Select the cell range you want to sort. 
2.Select the Data tab on the Ribbon, then click the Sort command. 
3.The Sort dialog box will appear.
4.Decide the sorting order (either ascending or descending). 
5.Once you're satisfied with your selection, click OK. 
6.The cell range will be sorted by the selected column.